# Remove margin or padding?

Tags: html, css

I don't know what is this. Is this margin or padding? How it is coming and from where? This is white space under the photo. I have reset code too but reset code doesn't work here.

**ScreenShot:**

[image: SS]

The Code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #7e8287;
}
.floatleft {
  float: left
}
.floatright {
  float: right
}
.colum {
  width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.fix {
  overflow: hidden
}
.clear {
  clear: both
}
.header_area {
  background: #02918c;
  min-height: 60px;
}
.header {} .header h1 {
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin-top: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.header a {
  color: #fff;
}
.header a h1 span {
  color: #cfc91d;
}
.mainmenu {} .mainmenu ul {} .mainmenu ul#nav {} .mainmenu ul#nav li {
  display: inline
}
.mainmenu ul#nav li a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
.mainmenu ul#nav li a:hover {} .welcome_text_area {
  background: url(../img/bg-2.jpg) no-repeat scroll center center / cover
}
.wel-overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7)
}
.welcome_text {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 200px 0
}
.welcome_text h1 {
  font-size: 68px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 5px 0;
  letter-spacing: 20px;
}
.welcome_text h4 {
  font-size: 30px;
}
.welcome_text p {
  font-size: 18px
}
.welcome_text a.know_more {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #cfc91d;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #0b1016;
  font-weight: 900;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 130px;
  position: relative
}
.welcome_text a.know_more:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "}";
  top: -145px;
  left: 90px;
  font-size: 120px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #fdfdfd;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.promo_area {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.colum {} .promo {} .promo_title,
.work_title {
  padding: 100px 0;
}
.promo_title h1,
.work_title h1 {
  color: #02918c;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 900;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  position: relative
}
.promo_title h1:before {
  content: "";
  background: url(../img/about-bg.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
  width: 160px;
  height: 10px;
  bottom: 27px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}
.promo_title p,
.work_title p {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #7e8287;
  padding: 0 115px;
}
.promo_title p span {
  font-size: 23px;
  color: #7e8287;
  font-weight: 900;
}
.promo_list {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 250px;
}
.promo_list div:last-child {
  border-right: 0
}
.single_list {
  width: 290px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  border-right: 1px solid #d9dbdb
}
.single_list h3 {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #7e8287;
  margin: 34px 0;
  font-weight: 900;
}
.single_list p {
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #7e8287;
}
.single_list img {} .service_area {
  background: #f0f0e8;
  position: relative
}
.rightimg {
  position: absolute;
  background: url(../img/rightimg.jpg) no-repeat scroll 0 0 / cover;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.3
}
.leftarea {
  width: 590px
}
.service_list {
  padding: 60px 60px;
}
.service_list h1 {
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 46px;
  color: #02918c;
  font-weight: 900;
  position: relative
}
.service_list h1:before {
  content: "";
  background: url(../img/about-bg.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
  width: 160px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -12px;
}
.service_list p {
  padding: 35px 0
}
.service_item .ss_list {
  width: 295px;
  padding-left: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: left
}
.service_item .ss_list h3 {
  padding: 20px 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.service_item .ss_list p {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.service_item .ss_list img {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.work_title h1 {
  text-align: center
}
.work_title p {
  max-width: 920px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.work_area {
  margin: 0;
}
.work_list {} .work_slider {
  width: 25%;
}
.work_slider img {
  width: 100%;
}
.slider_detail {} .slider_overlay {}
```

```html
<div class="work_area">
  <div class="colum">
    <div class="mywork">
      <div class="work_title fix">
        <h1>MY WORK</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="work_list fix">
    <div class="work_slider floatleft">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/317/238" />
      <div class="slider_detail">
        <div class="slider_overlay"></div>
        <h3></h3>
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="work_slider floatleft">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/317/238" />
      <div class="slider_detail">
        <div class="slider_overlay"></div>
        <h3></h3>
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="work_slider floatleft">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/317/238" />
      <div class="slider_detail">
        <div class="slider_overlay"></div>
        <h3></h3>
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="work_slider floatleft">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/317/238" />
      <div class="slider_detail">
        <div class="slider_overlay"></div>
        <h3></h3>
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="work_slider floatleft">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/317/238" />
      <div class="slider_detail">
        <div class="slider_overlay"></div>
        <h3></h3>
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="work_slider floatleft">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/317/238" />
      <div class="slider_detail">
        <div class="slider_overlay"></div>
        <h3></h3>
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="work_slider floatleft">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/317/238" />
      <div class="slider_detail">
        <div class="slider_overlay"></div>
        <h3></h3>
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="work_slider floatleft">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/317/238" />
      <div class="slider_detail">
        <div class="slider_overlay"></div>
        <h3></h3>
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I remove the white space?

Answer (score 1):

that gap is because `img` is an inline element, so set it `display:block`, so can be treated as block-level element

- you could also set it `vertical-align:bottom`, given `img` is by default `vertical-align:baseline`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #7e8287;
}
.floatleft {
  float: left
}
.floatright {
  float: right
}
.colum {
  width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.fix {
  overflow: hidden
}
.clear {
  clear: both
}
.header_area {
  background: #02918c;
  min-height: 60px;
}
.header {} .header h1 {
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin-top: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.header a {
  color: #fff;
}
.header a h1 span {
  color: #cfc91d;
}
.mainmenu {} .mainmenu ul {} .mainmenu ul#nav {} .mainmenu ul#nav li {
  display: inline
}
.mainmenu ul#nav li a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
.mainmenu ul#nav li a:hover {} .welcome_text_area {
  background: url(../img/bg-2.jpg) no-repeat scroll center center / cover
}
.wel-overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7)
}
.welcome_text {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 200px 0
}
.welcome_text h1 {
  font-size: 68px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 5px 0;
  letter-spacing: 20px;
}
.welcome_text h4 {
  font-size: 30px;
}
.welcome_text p {
  font-size: 18px
}
.welcome_text a.know_more {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #cfc91d;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #0b1016;
  font-weight: 900;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 130px;
  position: relative
}
.welcome_text a.know_more:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "}";
  top: -145px;
  left: 90px;
  font-size: 120px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #fdfdfd;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.promo_area {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.colum {} .promo {} .promo_title,
.work_title {
  padding: 100px 0;
}
.promo_title h1,
.work_title h1 {
  color: #02918c;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 900;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  position: relative
}
.promo_title h1:before {
  content: "";
  background: url(../img/about-bg.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
  width: 160px;
  height: 10px;
  bottom: 27px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}
.promo_title p,
.work_title p {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #7e8287;
  padding: 0 115px;
}
.promo_title p span {
  font-size: 23px;
  color: #7e8287;
  font-weight: 900;
}
.promo_list {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 250px;
}
.promo_list div:last-child {
  border-right: 0
}
.single_list {
  width: 290px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  border-right: 1px solid #d9dbdb
}
.single_list h3 {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #7e8287;
  margin: 34px 0;
  font-weight: 900;
}
.single_list p {
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #7e8287;
}
.single_list img {} .service_area {
  background: #f0f0e8;
  position: relative
}
.rightimg {
  position: absolute;
  background: url(../img/rightimg.jpg) no-repeat scroll 0 0 / cover;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.3
}
.leftarea {
  width: 590px
}
.service_list {
  padding: 60px 60px;
}
.service_list h1 {
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 46px;
  color: #02918c;
  font-weight: 900;
  position: relative
}
.service_list h1:before {
  content: "";
  background: url(../img/about-bg.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
  width: 160px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -12px;
}
.service_list p {
  padding: 35px 0
}
.service_item .ss_list {
  width: 295px;
  padding-left: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: left
}
.service_item .ss_list h3 {
  padding: 20px 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.service_item .ss_list p {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.service_item .ss_list img {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.work_title h1 {
  text-align: center
}
.work_title p {
  max-width: 920px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.work_area {
  margin: 0;
}
.work_list {} .work_slider {
  width: 25%;
}
.work_slider img {
  width: 100%;
  display:block
}
.slider_detail {} .slider_overlay {}
```

```html
<div class="work_area">
  <div class="colum">
    <div class="mywork">
      <div class="work_title fix">
        <h1>MY WORK</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="work_list fix">
    <div class="work_slider floatleft">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/317/238" />
      <div class="slider_detail">
        <div class="slider_overlay"></div>
        <h3></h3>
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="work_slider floatleft">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/317/238" />
      <div class="slider_detail">
        <div class="slider_overlay"></div>
        <h3></h3>
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="work_slider floatleft">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/317/238" />
      <div class="slider_detail">
        <div class="slider_overlay"></div>
        <h3></h3>
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="work_slider floatleft">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/317/238" />
      <div class="slider_detail">
        <div class="slider_overlay"></div>
        <h3></h3>
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="work_slider floatleft">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/317/238" />
      <div class="slider_detail">
        <div class="slider_overlay"></div>
        <h3></h3>
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="work_slider floatleft">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/317/238" />
      <div class="slider_detail">
        <div class="slider_overlay"></div>
        <h3></h3>
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="work_slider floatleft">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/317/238" />
      <div class="slider_detail">
        <div class="slider_overlay"></div>
        <h3></h3>
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="work_slider floatleft">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/317/238" />
      <div class="slider_detail">
        <div class="slider_overlay"></div>
        <h3></h3>
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

just add this:

```
.work_slider {
  line-height: 0;
}
```

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
a:hover {text-decoration: none;}
a:focus {text-decoration: none;}
a:visited {text-decoration: none;}
ul {margin: 0; padding: 0;list-style-type: none;}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {margin: 0; padding: 0}
body {font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; color:#7e8287;}
.floatleft {float: left}
.floatright {float: right}
.colum{width: 1170px; margin: 0 auto;}
.fix {overflow: hidden}
.clear {clear: both}



.header_area{background: #02918c; min-height: 60px;}
.header {}
.header h1 { font-size: 26px; font-weight: 900; margin-top: 15px; text-transform: uppercase;}
.header a {color: #fff;}
.header a h1 span{color: #cfc91d;}
.mainmenu {}
.mainmenu ul{}
.mainmenu ul#nav {}
.mainmenu ul#nav li{display: inline}
.mainmenu ul#nav li a {color:#fff; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 900; text-transform: uppercase; display: inline-block;padding-top: 20px; padding-left: 50px;}
.mainmenu ul#nav li a:hover{}


.welcome_text_area {background: url(../img/bg-2.jpg) no-repeat scroll center center / cover}
.wel-overlay {background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7)}
.welcome_text {text-align: center;color:#fff; padding: 200px 0}
.welcome_text h1 {font-size: 68px; font-weight: 900;text-transform: uppercase;margin: 5px 0;letter-spacing: 20px;}
.welcome_text h4 {font-size: 30px;}
.welcome_text p {font-size: 18px}
.welcome_text a.know_more {text-align: center; background-color: #cfc91d;display: inline-block; padding: 15px;color: #0b1016; font-weight: 900;width: 200px; height: 50px;margin-top: 130px; position: relative}
.welcome_text a.know_more:before {position: absolute;content: "}";top: -145px;left: 90px;font-size: 120px;font-weight: 100;color: #fdfdfd;transform: rotate(90deg);}


.promo_area {text-align: center; margin-bottom: 30px;}
.colum{}
.promo{}
.promo_title, .work_title {padding: 100px 0;}
.promo_title h1, .work_title h1 {color: #02918c; font-size: 48px; font-weight: 900;padding-bottom: 60px;position: relative}
.promo_title h1:before {content: "";background: url(../img/about-bg.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0;width: 160px;height: 10px;bottom: 27px;position: absolute;left: 50%;margin-left: -80px;}
.promo_title p, .work_title p {font-size:16px; color:#7e8287;padding: 0 115px;}
.promo_title p span {font-size:23px; color: #7e8287; font-weight: 900;}

.promo_list{text-align: center;margin-bottom: 250px;}
.promo_list div:last-child {border-right: 0}
.single_list {width: 290px; padding: 0 15px; border-right: 1px solid #d9dbdb}
.single_list h3 {font-size: 16px; color: #7e8287; margin: 34px 0; font-weight: 900;}
.single_list p {font-size: 11px; color: #7e8287;}
.single_list img {}


.service_area {background: #f0f0e8;position: relative}
.rightimg {position: absolute; background: url(../img/rightimg.jpg) no-repeat scroll 0 0 / cover; right: 0; top: 0; width:50%; height: 100%;opacity: 0.3}
.leftarea {width: 590px}
.service_list {padding: 60px 60px;}
.service_list h1 {padding: 20px 0; font-size: 46px; color: #02918c;font-weight: 900; position:relative}
.service_list h1:before {content: ""; background: url(../img/about-bg.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0;width: 160px; height: 10px;position: absolute;bottom: -12px;}
.service_list p {padding: 35px 0}

.service_item .ss_list {width: 295px;padding-left: 60px; padding-bottom: 30px; text-align: left}
.service_item .ss_list  h3 {padding: 20px 0;margin-bottom: 10px;}
.service_item .ss_list  p {margin-bottom: 15px;}
.service_item .ss_list  img {margin-bottom: 15px;}



.work_title h1 {text-align:center}
.work_title p { max-width: 920px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;}

.work_area {margin: 0;}
.work_list {}
.work_slider {width: 25%; line-height: 0;}
.work_slider img {width:100%;}
.slider_detail {}
.slider_overlay {}
```

```html
<div class="work_area">
            <div class="colum">
                <div class="mywork">
                    <div class="work_title fix">
                        <h1>MY WORK</h1>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="work_list fix">
                <div class="work_slider floatleft">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/317/238" />
                    <div class="slider_detail">
                       <div class="slider_overlay"></div>
                        <h3></h3>
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="work_slider floatleft">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/317/238" />
                    <div class="slider_detail">
                       <div class="slider_overlay"></div>
                        <h3></h3>
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="work_slider floatleft">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/317/238" />
                    <div class="slider_detail">
                       <div class="slider_overlay"></div>
                        <h3></h3>
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="work_slider floatleft">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/317/238" />
                    <div class="slider_detail">
                       <div class="slider_overlay"></div>
                        <h3></h3>
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="work_slider floatleft">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/317/238" />
                    <div class="slider_detail">
                       <div class="slider_overlay"></div>
                        <h3></h3>
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="work_slider floatleft">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/317/238" />
                    <div class="slider_detail">
                       <div class="slider_overlay"></div>
                        <h3></h3>
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="work_slider floatleft">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/317/238" />
                    <div class="slider_detail">
                       <div class="slider_overlay"></div>
                        <h3></h3>
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="work_slider floatleft">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/317/238" />
                    <div class="slider_detail">
                       <div class="slider_overlay"></div>
                        <h3></h3>
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: this is a "hack", not the best solution tho

Comment: for containers that only contain images (like here), this is perfectly fine.

Comment: again that's a "hack", `line-height` is **not** the cause of the problem here. It is always better to educate the OPs on why is causing the issue and then showing a possible solution, not a hack (only if is there is solution)

Comment: The space below the images is caused by the fact that the images are placed on the baseline of the container. Below that baseline there is space for the descenders of letters like"y", "g", "j" etc. - that's the white space that was there before. By setting line-height to 0 also this descender height is set to zero, so that removes that space and solves the problem. (enough "education"? ;-)

Comment: IMHO, not the best approach, because you can directly change the values causing the issue, such `baseline` to `bottom`